# C#: OpenXML numeric Excel cells not returning correct values

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

this is my first post so sorry if it doesn't look good or if the formatting is weird.

Anyways, I need to find a way to get the correct value of numeric (non-string) cells using OpenXML, but with some spreadsheets my current method doesn't seem to work.

There seems to be a difference in how I need to code for varying spreadsheets.

Once I've accessed an Excel file and have opened one of its Sheets I get the number of columns and rows for the current sheet and begin my loops. Within these loops is the code below that is used to add each cell to the datatable using the Cell Reference (made using the parent loops) as the guide. This is the looped through code:

```
//making the cell index/location of the cell (for example: B10, E17, AE14, ...) based on our row/column indexing so far
cellRef = ConvertColNumToLetter(startColNum + column) + (y + StartRow).ToString();
//getting the specific cell at the cell index of our cellRef
workingCell = cells.Where(c => c.CellReference == cellRef).FirstOrDefault();

//using a try-catch to solve the issue of the program failing whenever the cell has no inner text to take
try
{
    if (workingCell.InnerText == null)
        value = "";
    else
    {
        value = workingCell.InnerText;
    }

    //if the cell's data is a string
    if (workingCell.DataType != null && workingCell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
    {
        var stringTable = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (stringTable != null)
            value = stringTable.SharedStringTable.ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
        dataRow[colIterator] = value.ToString();
        colIterator++;
    }
    //if the cell's data is numeric
    else if (workingCell.CellValue != null)
    {
        value = workingCell.CellValue.InnerText.ToString();
        dataRow[colIterator] = value;
        colIterator++;
    }
    //if the cell doesn't have any data
    else
    {
        dataRow[colIterator] = "";
        colIterator++;
    }
}
//this will only fail if the cell didn't have any data/the data is null
catch
{
    dataRow[colIterator] = "";
    colIterator++;
}
```

My code works just fine for 99% of the spreadsheets it encounters. My only problem is with numeric values not being accessed correctly on one specific spreadsheet but it seems to get the correct numeric values on all other spreadsheets.

With the normal spreadsheets, whatever numeric value that is stored in the formula is returned. As an example, here is a cell's value from one such spreadsheet: "31313308.87". When my program reaches that cell, here is the workingCell's details (the workingCell is the cell at the current cell reference location):

[image: CellValue and InnerText match the desired value]

which as you can see are the values that I would want and would go through the program and store the correct values into the datatable.

But the spreadsheet that's giving me issues is strange. When I get to one of the numeric cells I end up just getting the completely wrong values. Opening up the actual spreadsheet, there is a numeric cell with a value of "502028.6", but my program gets this in the workingCell's details: 
[image: CellValue and InnerText are both completely wrong]

I'm not sure where the "279907" comes from or how I should go about getting the correct values.

Here's another strange thing. The next three values of the spreadsheet are zeros which all return 0 in the CellValue and InnerText of the workingCell. The next value on the spreadsheet is "-160", and in the workingCell's details it shows:

[image: CellValue and InnerText are wrong yet again]

1500 in the CellValue and InnerText?

Again, this is the only spreadsheet that this is happening on (or at least the only one that I know of). The program returns the correct string values as well, but on this one specific spreadsheet, none of the numeric values seem to be picked up with my program (despite it working and returning the correct numeric values for the hundreds of other spreadsheets I've used it on so far).

Is there some simple fix that I'm just not seeing? I would love any pointers or suggestions you may have for me, and I will be happy to clarify anything if you need some additional information.

Thank you for all of your help in advance!

--EDIT:
I forgot to specify when I asked the question, but the incorrect data (the incorrect CellValues and InnerTexts) is actually successfully processed into the else if statement then added to the datatable. I don't have any problem as far as adding values to the datatable goes, but I just can't seem to get the correct CellValues and InnerTexts for numeric cells on the one specific spreadsheet

Comment: You will have to fix that exception handling. Right now you catch and try to handle fatal exceptions - wich is the one thing you should never try to do. Indeed you should not even run into a null related exception to begin with. Here are two articles on proper exception handling that I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET Once you fixed that exception handling code, you should have the minimum amount fo data to actually debug the problem

Comment: @Christopher I know the exception handling is bad, but this isn't the final project just yet. I forgot to specify, but the issue occurs in the else if statement. I don't get any errors In the spreadsheets I mentioned and to find the issues, I debugged and looked at the values of the variables as the program moved forwards. The data is actually handled without using the catch.  It ends up being processed into the else if statement and is added to the datatable successfully, but the values just aren't correct and debugger just didn't help me to find the issue.

Comment: This may be a dumb question of me, but are you sure you're on the correct worksheet within the file? Do the values like "277907" exist *somewhere else* in that sheet/workbook perhaps?

Comment: @DavidZemens That's not a dumb question at all. I do have a variable that contains the filepath and set it to the specific spreadsheet that I want, and same thing with the worksheet name.  Then before I open the file I display the entire path that I'm using, and I do the same thing again with the worksheet name, so I know that I'm in the correct file/worksheet.  And unfortunately the 279907 and 1500 aren't actually on that specific spreadsheet or any of the other spreadsheets within the file in either the formula or the values

Comment: Could you include the full XML from the problem cell(s) as example? Might help isolate the problem.

Comment: Are you able to provide a sample file that causes the incorrect values to be read?